# Node.js and lodash - clone JSON object returning only specific element

Tags: json, node.js, clone, lodash

I have a requirement to clone a JSON object however drop specific elements. I am attempting to use lodash clone(). Test code:

```
var _ = require('lodash');

var obj = {
    "config": {
        "items": [
            {
                "k1": "foo",
                "k2": "xx",
                "k3": "yy"

            },
            {
                "k1": "bar",
                "k2": "zz",
                "k3": "aa"
            }
        ]
    }
};

var clone = _.cloneDeep(obj, function(value) {

    // debug
    if(value.k2 == "xx"){
        console.log(value);
    }

    return value.k2 == "xx" ? value : undefined;
});

console.log("CLONE:  "+JSON.stringify(clone));
```

I would like to return a clone object, but only with the items where K2= "xx". Executing the above shows that the correct items is being found, but the returned cloned object also includes all other items:

```
{ k1: 'foo', k2: 'xx', k3: 'yy' }
CLONE:  {"config":{"items":[{"k1":"foo","k2":"xx","k3":"yy"},{"k1":"bar","k2":"zz","k3":"aa"}]}}
```

Can anyone advise how I can clone and drop specific elements?

UPDATE: To be clear, I need to two objects. The original must be intact, and then the cloned version with only the desired properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var obj = {
    "config": {
        "items": [
            {
                "k1": "foo",
                "k2": "xx",
                "k3": "yy"

            },
            {
                "k1": "bar",
                "k2": "zz",
                "k3": "aa"
            }
        ]
    }
};    

var cloneObj = _.cloneDeep(obj);

cloneObj.config.items = cloneObj.config.items.filter(function(item) {
   return item.k2 === 'xx';
});


console.log(obj);
console.log(cloneObj);
```

Comment: From the wording I believe the idea is to clone then delete, not delete then clone.

Comment: I  dont think its matter at all...let him decide.

Comment: @JsIsAwesome - thanks so much and apologies for not being clear. As cbajorin suggest, I do indeed to clone then delete. The requirement is to have both the original object untouched and a modified clone. Updated my question accordingly.

Comment: @JsIsAwesome - great stuff, thats really helpful :)